# Ordenar los valores de un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo un archivo JSON, y lo que quiero hacer es hacer una función en la que devuelva una lista ordenada limitada por 10 usuarios (si es posible, en un array, pero si eso es complicarse, agradecería su sugerencia).

Estos datos provienen de:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

En la cual accedo a los datos de cada uno con la siguiente línea:

```
let userData = points[msg.author.id];
```

El archivo JSON tiene el siguiente formato.

```
{
  "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
  "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
  "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}
```

De momento, lo que tengo es un programa que lo que hace es que añade puntos a los usuarios (y conforme alcancen 'x' puntos, suben de nivel automáticamente), pero ahora necesito hacer una lista del "top 10 usuarios más activos".

Lo que necesito es que al ordenar, devuelva la ID (en el primer caso sería *242043489611808769*), que es lo que necesito para poder procesar los datos.

Trabajo con NodeJS, gracias por adelantado.

Comment: De donde obtienes esos datos? Cual es la query que haces,

Comment: Oh, ahora actualizo la pregunta

Comment: Estoy preparando la respuesta, estoy depurando el código :)

Comment: Ya lo tienes, me daba error porque no me di cuenta que el envoltorio principal es de objeto (`{}`), no de matriz (`[]`), así que he tenido que convertir el objeto en matriz antes de usar `sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el siguiente código para ordenar los datos y obtener el más alto:

```js
/* Los datos que has proporcionado en el ejemplo */
var json = '{\
  "242043489611808769": {\
    "points": 617,\
    "level":4,\
    "time":1482316617392\
  },\
  "129213229221019648": {\
    "points": 22,\
    "level":0,\
    "time":1482316617609\
  },\
  "190388892799598592": {\
    "points":214,\
    "level":2,\
    "time":1482316612355\
  }\
}';
/* Tratamos los datos */
var points = JSON.parse(json);
/* Los convertimos en un array añadiendo el "id" a los campos */
var points_array = Object.keys(points).map(
  function (clave) {
    var elemento = points[clave];
    elemento.id = clave;
    return elemento;
  }
);
/* Los ordenamos comparando los puntos (points) */
points_array.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  }
);
/* Obtenemos el primer elemento (el mayor) */
console.log(points_array[0]);
console.log(points_array[0].id);
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Ese código, como es de esperar, devuelve todos los datos del usuario con mayor puntaje:

{
  "points": 617,
  "level": 4,
  "time": 1482316617392,
  "id": "242043489611808769"
}

Cuando ejecuto **points_array[0].points** me devuelve *617* (el valor más alto), sin embargo, he intentado obtener la ID con **points_array[0].id** y me devuelve *undefined*, ¿cómo lo resuelvo?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta para agregar la salida exacta del `id`. Podrás comprobar que funciona correctamente. Cuidado, quizá no has actualizado el código en el que creé la matriz añadiendo el campo `id`.

Comment: No había actualizado la página, la edición ha servido, muchas gracias

Comment: De paso, revisa que la comparación es entre los campos `points`. En mi primera respuesta comparé los campos `level` por error.

Comment: Sí, lo había cambiado al añadir el código, ahora está funcionando a la perfección, gracias

Comment: Una pregunta señor @OscarGarcia , ¿cómo obtengo la posición (ordenada por el campo points) de un usuario conforme su ID de usuario? He probado con los métodos `indexOf()`, `find()`... pero no logro hacer que coincidan los objetos para que devuelva un valor válido, ya que no puedo hacer `points_array[].id.indexOf()` porque para empezar no se puede hacer en Javascript. He intentado también con:
`points_array.find(function(a){return a.id == msg.author.id});` pero nada...

Comment: No te puedo poner el código aquí, abre un nuevo hilo y en cuanto pueda me conecto para contestarte (si no se adelanta otra persona)

Comment: De acuerdo, aquí está el [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40631/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-obtener-la-posici%C3%B3n-de-un-objeto-json)