# Ordenar un array JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Anteriormente, en [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40311/ordenar-los-valores-de-un-archivo-json) pedí ayuda para hacer una especie de top de usuarios ordenados por su puntuación, usando un archivo JSON definido como

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

Con el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
  "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
  "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}
```

Y lo hacía con el siguiente código:

```
var points = JSON.parse(json);
var points_array = Object.keys(points).map(
  function (clave) {
    var elemento = points[clave];
    elemento.id = clave;
    return elemento;
  }
);
points_array.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  }
);
```

Sin embargo, ahora necesito ordenar otro archivo JSON, definido como

```
let lpoints = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./lpoints.json', 'utf8'));
```

Con el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "256566731684839428":[
    {"ID":"242043489611808769", "points":617},
    {"ID":"129213229221019648", "points":22},
    {"ID":"190388892799598592", "points":214}
  ]
}
```

Siendo `256566731684839428` la ID del `guild`, y cada bloque, la ID del usuario y su puntuación.

```
var lguild = lpoints[msg.guild.id];
if (lguild === undefined) {
  lpoints[msg.guild.id] = []
  var newGuild = lpoints[msg.guild.id];
  newGuild.push({id:msg.author.id, points: 0});
}else{
  var userX = lguild.find( function(element) {
    return element.ID === msg.author.id;
  });
  if(userX === undefined) {
    lguild.push({id:msg.author.id, points: 0});
  }
}
```

Éste es el código que actualiza los datos, por si necesitas el contexto y entender mejor cómo funciona el código, aunque está explicado en [éste otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40380/datos-de-usuario-asignados-%C3%BAnicamente-a-un-servidor).

Lo que necesito es, al igual que mi programa ahora está ordenando los datos del archivo `./points.json` (arriba del todo), que ordene también los datos del archivo `./lpoints.json`, pero sólo de un determinado array (`msg.guild.id`).

He intentado hacer algo parecido al código que uso para ordenar los datos de usuario globales (points.json), pero no sé cómo ordenar los objetos dentro de un array.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Ojo que el JSON tiene una coma de más antes del `]`

Comment: Era una muestra "recortada" del archivo json y olvidé quitar esa coma, ese archivo tiene por lo menos 200 objetos y han sido escritos a través del programa. Aunque buena observación.

Comment: Me imaginé @Antonio, el tema era también para avisar que había que corregirlo antes de probar tu ejemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código es exactamente el mismo, sólo que ahora el array a ordenar es `lpoints[msg.guild.id]`.

Código:

```js
//para simular el JSON obtenido
var jsonObtenido = `{
  "256566731684839428":[
    {"ID":"242043489611808769", "points":617},
    {"ID":"129213229221019648", "points":22},
    {"ID":"190388892799598592", "points":214}
  ]
}`;

//El ID que se quiere ordenar (simulamos lo que usa el autor)
var msg = { guild: { id: "256566731684839428" }}; 

// convertir en objeto
// Esta línea en realidad debería ser: 
//let lpoints = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./lpoints.json', 'utf8'));
var lpoints = JSON.parse(jsonObtenido);

//ordenar (si existe)
if (lpoints[msg.guild.id]) {
    lpoints[msg.guild.id].sort(
        function (a, b) {
            return b.points - a.points;
        }
    );
}

//Mostrar el resultado
console.log(lpoints);
```

Comment: ¿Entonces hay que cerrar la pregunta como duplicada?

Comment: @ArtEze no sé. Creo que está pidiendo aclaración sobre cómo interpretar ese código con un tema en particular que es distinto... Pero da igual.