# Guardar información de dos niveles (servidor y usuarios) en SQLite

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite, collectionjs

Trabajo en **NodeJS**, anteriormente, había hecho lo siguiente: [Ordenar un array JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40526/ordenar-un-array-json), lo cual me fue excelente (hasta que Windows decidió hacer un pantallazo azul y borrar todos mis datos).

Actualmente, tengo dos bases de datos, ambos en **SQLite**, uno guarda las puntuaciones de los usuarios de manera global (se almacenan sus puntuaciones y son válidos para todos los servidores). Sin embargo, ahora quiero hacerlo de dos niveles, como en el anterior enlace que he compartido.

Se debe cumplir que: cada servidor tiene una serie de datos únicos, y el usuario puede tener diferentes puntuaciones. Por ejemplo, un usuario "X" puede tener "A" puntos en un servidor "Y" y "B" puntos en un servidor "Z".

Había pensado en usar un campo **blob** y insertando caracteres especiales, hacer split y almacenar todos los datos en una colección. Sin embargo, a cada usuario le corresponde una ID de 18 caracteres, y una puntuación, de modo que si almaceno cada usuario en un campo **blob**, acabaré teniendo un texto como `242043489611808769 : 1234 |` pero con centenas de usuarios, y no me gustaría llegar a algún tipo de problema por exceso de palabras.

Entonces, sólo se me ocurren dos maneras:

1. Crear una tabla dedicada para cada servidor, y almacenar todos los usuarios en rows de dos campos.
2. Crear una tabla con todos los servidores, y almacenar en un campo **blob**, todos los usuarios y sus puntuaciones.

Lo que necesito es, obtener la máxima eficiencia posible. Y en el caso de ser el primero, ¿cómo podría obtener todos los usuarios de todas las tablas del archivo?

Actualmente, uso el siguiente código para almacenar los puntos (globales) de todos los usuarios:

```
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
client.scores = new client.methods.Collection();
sqlite.open('points.sqlite').then(() => {
  sqlite.all('SELECT * FROM users').then(rows => {
    rows.forEach(row => {
      client.scores.set(row.ID, row);
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT: Esto en JSON sería mucho más fácil, ya que haría que un servidor sea un array de objectos (en la cual, cada objeto es un usuario con su ID y su puntuación local), sin embargo, necesito lograr lo mismo, pero en SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Se debe cumplir que: cada servidor tiene una serie de datos únicos, y **el usuario puede tener diferentes puntuaciones**. Por ejemplo, **un usuario "X" puede tener "A" puntos en un servidor** "Y" y "B" puntos en un servidor "Z"

Aquí hay una clara relación `N * M` que se materializa en una tabla de unión `Puntuaciones`.

> Había pensado en usar un campo blob y insertando caracteres especiales, hacer split y almacenar todos los datos en una colección. Sin embargo, **a cada usuario le corresponde una ID de 18 caracteres**, y una puntuación, de modo que si almaceno cada usuario en un campo blob, acabaré teniendo un texto como `242043489611808769 : 1234 |` pero con centenas de usuarios

Normaliza tu base de datos, así mantienes consistencia entre tablas.

---

**Análisis**

No veo la necesidad de tener varias bases de datos. Una sola puede almacenar suficiente información para usuarios, servidores y puntuaciones. Veo tres tablas aquí: `Servidores`, `Usuarios` y `Puntuaciones`, donde esta última sería la tabla de unión:

[image: ER]

De éste modo mantienes tu base de datos pequeña, ya que en las puntuaciones solo existirán foráneas a servidores y usuarios. Si quieres máxima eficiencia, puedes usar índices.

Por ejemplo, obtener las puntuaciones de un usuario por su `uuid`:

```
db.get(`SELECT u.nombre AS 'usuario', s.nombre AS 'servidor', p.puntos AS 'puntos' FROM usuarios u
  INNER JOIN puntajes p ON p.usuario_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN servidores s ON s.id = p.servidor_id
  WHERE u.uuid = ?`,
  req.params.uuid
)
.then((rows) => {
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    let usuario = row.usuario;
    let servidor = row.servidor;
    let puntos = row.puntos;
  });
});
```