# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la posición de un objeto json?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Mi programa carga un archivo json, lo lee y lo escribe, pero además, tiene una función, los ordena por la cantidad de puntos. El anterior paso que he hecho en mi programa está [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40311/ordenar-los-valores-de-un-archivo-json/40316?noredirect=1#comment69562_40316).

Los datos a procesar provienen de:

```
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./points.json', 'utf8'));
```

El formato del archivo `./points.json` es el siguiente:

```
{
  "242043489611808769":{"points":617,"level":4,"time":1482316617392},
  "129213229221019648":{"points":22,"level":0,"time":1482316617609},
  "190388892799598592":{"points":214,"level":2,"time":1482316612355}
}
```

Y por último, los datos son ordenados conforme la cantidad de puntos, a través del siguiente bloque de código:

```
var points_array = Object.keys(points).map(
  function (clave) {
    var elemento = points[clave];
    elemento.id = clave;
    return elemento;
  }
);
points_array.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  }
);
```

Con la cual, `points_array[0].id` devolvería la **id** del usuario con mayor valor de **points**. Sin embargo, necesito saber cómo puedo obtener la posición del usuario ordenada en función del campo **points** a partir del campo **id**, es decir, quiero, por ejemplo, buscar la posición que tiene el usuario **190388892799598592**, la cual debería devolver **1** (617 > 214 > 22).

He probado con varios códigos pero no he conseguido hacer que devuelva otra cosa que **-1** (not found). Uno de ellos es el siguiente:

```
points_array.find(
  function(a) {
    return a.id == msg.author.id;
  }
);
```

Pero devuelve **-1**...

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas. Si la búsqueda es esporádica (una única vez) es mejor implementar una función que recorra la matriz hasta encontrar tu identificador. Si vas a hacer muchas búsquedas (vas a mostrar la posición de varios identificadores) entonces lo mejor es almacenar las posiciones en una matriz asociativa:

```js
/* Los datos que has proporcionado en el ejemplo */
var json = '{\
  "242043489611808769": {\
    "points": 617,\
    "level":4,\
    "time":1482316617392\
  },\
  "129213229221019648": {\
    "points": 22,\
    "level":0,\
    "time":1482316617609\
  },\
  "190388892799598592": {\
    "points":214,\
    "level":2,\
    "time":1482316612355\
  }\
}';
/* Tratamos los datos */
var points = JSON.parse(json);
/* Los convertimos en un array añadiendo el "id" a los campos */
var points_array = Object.keys(points).map(
  function (clave) {
    var elemento = points[clave];
    elemento.id = clave;
    return elemento;
  }
);
/* Los ordenamos comparando los puntos (points) */
points_array.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return b.points - a.points;
  }
);
/* Obtenemos el primer elemento (el mayor) */
console.log(points_array[0]);
console.log(points_array[0].id);

/* Creamos una función que haga el trabajo */
function encontrar_id(array, elemento) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id == elemento) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

/* Hacemos uso de la función */
console.log("Posición de '129213229221019648': " +
  encontrar_id(points_array, "129213229221019648")
);
console.log("Posición de '242043489611808769': " +
  encontrar_id(points_array, "242043489611808769")
);
console.log("Posición de '190388892799598592': " +
  encontrar_id(points_array, "190388892799598592")
);
console.log("Posición de '290388892799598592': " +
  encontrar_id(points_array, "290388892799598592")
);

/* Creamos una matriz asociativa id -> posicion */
posiciones = {};
for (i = 0; i < points_array.length;) {
  posiciones[points_array[i].id] = ++i;
}
console.log(posiciones);

/* Hacemos uso de este método */
console.log("Posición de '129213229221019648': " +
  posiciones["129213229221019648"]
);
console.log("Posición de '242043489611808769': " +
  posiciones["242043489611808769"]
);
console.log("Posición de '190388892799598592': " +
  posiciones["190388892799598592"]
);
console.log("Posición de '290388892799598592': " +
  posiciones["290388892799598592"]
);
```

En caso de no encontrar el identificador, tanto la función como la matriz devolverán `undefined`.